# Ant FTP task - prevent transferring some files/directories

Tags: ant, ftp

I want to upload a local folder to my website's FTP with an Ant task like this one:

```
<ftp password="mypwd" server="myown.server.com" 
    userid="user" 
    passive="true"
    remotedir="myfolder/templates">
    <fileset dir="myfolder/templates">
        <include name="**/*.html"/>
    </fileset>
</ftp>
```

Unfortunately there are some files I do not want (like CVS, or some commentary files)

I checked on the Ant FTP task documentation but I am quite new to these concept.

How to prevent some files to be sent to the FTP?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [fileset docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).

Your example should already exclude any file which doesn't end in `.html`, as once you add an `include` to a patternset only matched files are included.

To exclude files in CVS directories, try `<exclude name="**/CVS/**/*"/>`

Answer (score 2):

This is very easy:

First, the [Apache Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) relates to the type "Fileset".

With this, you can also exclude any kind of files like the following example:

```
<ftp password="mypwd" server="myown.server.com" 
    userid="user" 
    passive="true"
    remotedir="myfolder/templates">
    <fileset dir="myfolder/templates">
        <include name="**/*.html"/>
        <exclude name="**/CVS"/>
        <exclude name="**/readme.*"/>
    </fileset>
</ftp>
```

This will exclude all the CVS directories (any folder/subfolder they can be present) and every files called "readme.*".

Comment: You meant to link to the [fileset docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).